# PHP include with HTTP get paramters

Tags: php

How would one go about using php include() with GET paramters on the end of the included path?

IE:

```
include("/home/site/public_html/script.php?id=5");
```

Comment: That is just not possible. `include` reads the file form the file system and does not initiate a HTTP request.

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you trying to do? If you need to pass a value to the `script.php` it will be able to read the existing `$_GET` in the calling script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would one go about using php include() with GET paramters on the end of the included path?

You *could* write into `$_GET`:

```
$_GET["id"] = 5;   // Don't do this at home!
include(".....");
```

but that feels kludgy and wrong. If at all possible, make the included file accept normal variables:

```
$id = 5;
include("....."); // included file handles `$id`
```

Comment: Might be even tidier to have a function or class in the included file, and pass the required variables as arguments to the function/constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You don't, `include` loads files via the local filesystem.

Comment: Unless the specified path is a url, in which case an 'http://' type path WOULD be requested via http, but that's highly ugly and incredibly insecure.

Comment: yes, it's possible, but oh so horrible. (If "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can do it, you can also make me projectile-vomit this way too.)

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to, you could just do this, which would have the same result.

```
<?php
    $_GET['id'] = 5;
    include "/home/site/public_html/script.php";
?>
```

but then you might as well just define the variable and include it

```
<?php
    $id = 5; 
    include "/home/site/public_html/script.php";
?>
```

and reference the variable as `$id` inside script.php.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use:

```
include("http://localhost/include/that/thing.php?id=554&y=16");
```

But that's very seldomly useful.

It **might** be possible to write a [stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) for that, so it becomes possible for local scripts too.

```
include("withvars:./include/that/thing.php?id=554");
```

I'm not aware if such a solution exists yet.